# Flush() not working in drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I'm trying to post data from one node to another. The other node contains the for loop which iterates for long time and finally generates the table. I want to display the result after each iteration. I have tried to put "flush();" but it is not working. What should i do to display each iteration result on the node page?

Note:
If i do it with ob_flush() it works but it then starts printing data above the header which is not suitable. I want all the data inside the node.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for the [Batch API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/group/batch).